# Python Reading value from xml and convert it to float

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, traceback

I'm reading a value from an xml file into a dictionary.

The value is:

```
10**-3
```

I want to cast it into a float. It should be like:

```
>> myval = 10**-3
>> print myval
>> print type(myval)
>> 
>> 0.001
>> <type 'float'>
```

But the value from the xml is a string and i keep getting the error:

```
>> float(mydict["value"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 10**-3
```

So it is not possible to cast this string into a float, but i need to get it to work.

Is there an easy way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval`

**Ex:**

```
eval(mydict["value"])
```

Comment: @DopeX Be careful, `eval` _can_ be dangerous - https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for the advise. I will look into it.